# regex--how to match a parentheses followed by non-digit characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I am making a question database, and the way that I've made the database is by splitting a string into an array of smaller strings, where each is a question and its answer. For example, the string I have looks like

```
var string = "(1) foo? ANSWER: fee (2) fah. ANSWER: feh"
```

The way I'm splitting the string into the array is with the following `.match`:

```
const arr = string
  .match(/\(\d+[^(]+/g)
  });
```

The regex in `.match` splits the large string of questions into an array of strings. The way it is now, the match starts at a opening parenthesis of the number of a question and matches everything up until the next opening parenthesis, which is the start of the next question's number. So the resulting array looks like

```
 ["(1) foo? ANSWER: fee", "(2) fah. ANSWER: feh"]
```

This works perfectly fine except when the question itself has parentheses:

```
var string = "(1) foo foo (faa) foo? ANSWER: fee (2) fah. ANSWER: fah"
```

The .match function in this case makes a split at the ( in (faa, which throws off the array. How can I modify the regex expression so that it will match an opening parentheses followed by an infinite number of non-parentheses characters, but match a parentheses so long as it is followed by a non-digit character?

Comment: Why are you parsing strings instead of just storing the data in objects and arrays to begin with?

Comment: `const questions = [{ "q":"foo foo (faa)","a":"fee"}, {"q":"fah?","a":"fah!"}]` which you can store after JSON.stringify and read with JSON.parse (or just ajax as JSON)

Comment: Yes, I know that's more practical. The thing is, I'm copy-pasting thousands of questions (which I didn't write) and I don't have the time to put each one in an object with properties. My goal here is to take my massive string of questions, parse it into strings of questions and their answers, and then turn those substrings into objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split using the position that asserts what is on the right are one or more digits between parenthesis.

```
(?=\(\d+\))
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yDfHb0/1)

```js
var string = "(1) foo foo (faa) foo? ANSWER: fee (2) fah. ANSWER: fah" 
console.log(string.split(/(?=\(\d+\))/g));
```

Comment: This works great. Could you explain how the lookahead function works?

Comment: The positive lookahead `(?=` is an assertion which is non consuming and checks what is directly to the right is in this case 1 or more digits between parenthesis.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!